# Save the smart table content whe the button is clicked

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 , I want add the smart table content to a new json file when I click on the save button. Is it possible ?

```html
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
    constructor(private http : Http){
      this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(data =>{ this.obj = data
      this.source.load(this.obj);});
    }
    
    SaveData()
    {
     
     alert(JSON.stringify(this.Cost));
    // this is function which will active when the save button is pressed.
    }
```

[image]

when click on the save button I want to overwrite the existing json1 file from the server. I there any solution for this ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a web service which overwrites the data on the server. You can overwrite this data on the client side or in local storage but in order to update server you need make a service which overwrites the JSON file with your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I used LUA server side scripting language to do the process. How can I post the object to LUA 

I Used : this.http.post('http://192.168.0.100:80/login/save.lua',JSON.stringify(this.Cost)) . Is it correct ?? But I can't access it from lua